# Connect to Windows 8 computer File share through Explorer with live account

Tags: windows-8, file-sharing

How can I connect to a windows 8 computer running a file share (C$ for instance), with a Microsoft account. I have tried various forms of login, and even found workarounds that could get it working through some registry workarounds, but I just want to be able to connect from Win 8 laptop to C$ on Win 8 desktop without having to set up homegroup or domain or anything fancy.

Comment: use "MicrosoftAccount\email" as username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually signed up just to help other people who are still struggeling with this. Login with Microsoft Account / Live ID is possible if you put `microsoftaccount\` before the user name. So a Win 8 Installation with the Live Account john.doe@yahoo.cz can remotely login to his shares with `microsoftaccount\john.doe@yahoo.cz` and the appropriate password.

I found out about this quite fast while looking to connect via RDP to a Win8 machine. However I struggled for a while because it won't work with the default administrative shares. They are disabled on 8.1 ...

Comment: This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

On the "server" you can try running a cmd prompt as admin and then type (for example):

```
net share desired_share_name=c:\foo /grant:Everyone,full
```

The share should then be visible when browsing the local network. (or via `//servername/desired_share_name`)

(documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750728.aspx)

Comment: It still asks for a login. My username is PersonEmail45@gmail.com on my live account on both computers, how do i log in to the share?